# NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined alternate function (glGenFramebuffers, glGenFramebuffersEXT)

Tags: python, pyopengl

Currently I'm working with 3D objects rendering. In that while dealing with framebuffer part I'm getting some error.

self.fbo = glGenFramebuffers(1)

whenever interpreter hits this line its showing following error

```
**File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 44, in __call__
    self._finalCall = self.finalise()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\extensions.py", line 189, in finalise
    self.__name__,
NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined alternate function (glGenFramebuffers, glGenFramebuffersEXT), check for bool(glGenFramebuffers) before calling**
```

I'm using python 2.7.3 and pyOpenGL 3.0.2.I couldn't find any answer for this error.

Answer (score 3):

If `bool(glGenFramebuffers)` returns **False**, the error probably means that your computer does not have access to OpenGL >= 2.1 so Framebufffer objects won't work. Check your OpenGL supported version with [GPU Caps Viewer](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/) for Windows. For Linux see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/47062/what-is-terminal-command-that-can-show-opengl-version

If you have at least 2.1, then maybe the library you are using to create the context (pySDL, glut, pySFML, etc.) is not creating a compatible one. Fixing that depends on the library and probably already has an answer.

If `bool(glGenFramebuffers)` returns **True**, the problem might be somewhere else early in the code.

Also, remember that the context must be created and current before trying to create or use shaders, framebuffers, etc.